# Problema con menú emergente en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, menú

He creado un programa que tiene una barra de menús superior y un menú contextual que se activa al hacer clic derecho sobre el canvas.
En el menú superior las funciones solo se ejecutan al hacer click izquierdo, pero en el emergente se ejecutan tanto con el izquierdo como con el derecho y eso no es lo que quiero.
Os dejo el código.

```
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-
import tkinter


def funcion1():
    print('Función 1 ejecutada.')

def funcion2():
    print('Función 2 ejecutada.')

def click_der(event):
    popup.post(event.x_root, event.y_root)

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Prueba menu contextual")
#===============================================================================
# Barra superior
#===============================================================================
menuBar = tkinter.Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menuBar)
menu1 = tkinter.Menu(menuBar, tearoff=0)
menu1.add_command(label="Función 1", command=funcion1)
menu1.add_command(label="Función 2", command=funcion2)
menuBar.add_cascade(label="Menu 1", menu=menu1)
#===============================================================================
# Menu contextual
#===============================================================================
popup = tkinter.Menu(root, tearoff=0)
popup.add_command(label='Función 1', command=funcion1)
popup.add_command(label='Función 2', command=funcion2)
root.bind("<Button-3>", click_der)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

El menú emergente funciona de sea manera porque tú así definiste su comportamiento.

```
#aqui estas creando el menu emergente
popup = tkinter.Menu(root, tearoff=0)
#aqui estas mostrando el boton que llama la funcion 1
popup.add_command(label='Función 1', command=funcion1)
#aqui estas mostrando el boton que llama la funcion 2
popup.add_command(label='Función 2', command=funcion2)
#aca lo configuras para mostrarlo cuando hagas clic derecho
root.bind("<Button-3>", click_der)

root.mainloop()
```

Edita tu pregunta. De lo contrario va se difícil que alguien te ayude. ¿Qué es lo que se supone que debería hacer tu código al hacer clic derecho?

Comment: El programa funciona bien. Lo único que quiero modificar es que cuando aparece el menú emergente se puede seleccionar una de las 2 opciones haciendo click tanto con el botón izquierdo como con el derecho del ratón. Yo quiero que solo sea posible hacerlo con el botón izquierdo, igual que sucede en el menú superior.